# oracle sql stored procedure

Tags: sql, oracle, stored-procedures

I am having trouble understanding how to create a stored procedure. Mostly I am having trouble understanding what a parameter is. I keep obtaining the error "SQL command not properly ended".

I believe it is because of my parameters. I am trying to create a procedure that will update my sold column based off of two other columns.

```
CREATE TABLE sales
(
    price_per_unit NUMBER NOT NULL,
    price_sold NUMBER NOT NULL,
    sold NUMBER,
    profit NUMBER
);

CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE update_profit
(
    price_per_unit NUMBER,
    price_sold NUMBER,
    sold NUMBER
)
AS
BEGIN
    UPDATE sales
    SET profit = ((price_sold * sold) - (price_per_unit * sold))
    COMMIT;
END;
/
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Syntactically, you're missing a semi-colon at the end of your update statement.  You also do not have a PROFIT column on your table, so your update isn't going to compile once you do add that semi-colon.

Programatically, you're probably going to be much happier using a view:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW SALES_V
AS 
SELECT  PRICE_PER_UNIT, 
        PRICE_SOLD, 
        SOLD, 
        ((PRICE_SOLD * SOLD) - (PRICE_PER_UNIT * SOLD)) PROFIT
FROM    SALES;
```

(it's generally bad practice to physically store derived results)

Comment: I missed that semi-colon in my comment.

Comment: Yes I noticed that I had forgotten the sold parameter and have changed it.

Comment: I am required to make a procedure for this assignment. My book shows the formula for creating a procedure exactly how I have it above except mine is producing errors.

Comment: Adding the semi-colon made it work! Thank you very much for the help. Im looking at the page about procedures now and none of my books examples use a semi-colon in that location.

Answer (score 0):

There is a syntax error in your parameter list.

Change

```
(
price_per_unit NUMBER,
price_sold NUMBER
)
```

To

```
(
price_per_unit IN NUMBER,
price_sold IN NUMBER
)
```

You need to specify whether a parameter is read only (IN) write only (OUT) or read-and-write (IN OUT).

As for the error you report , can you please say how you are running the code? SQLPlus or SQLDeveloper/TOAD?

Comment: I am still getting the same error when I add IN to the parameters.

Comment: Parameters default to `in`. It is not necessary to explicitly include the 'in' keyword, although it is better practice in my opinion.